# Embed BBC News Live Stream Onto Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, stream, embed

I am wanting to embed BBC News Live stream into  website for a digital signage.

Sky News is easy as it is a youtube live stream however it MUST be BBC News only.

I have managed to use an iframe through TV Catch Up however this is very intermittent and doesn't seem like the best solution.

`<iframe width="100%" height="900" src="http://tvcatchup.com/watch/bbcnews"></iframe>`

I want to embed it straight from the BBC News website with subtitles enabled. This is the link to the video on the website -
 https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/live/bbcnews

After looking at the source code I found the video src is `blob:https://emp.bbc.co.uk/dc8c567e-083e-42ae-86e4-7fd4ca7de39b`

Surely this shouldn't be this difficult? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: how is `STEAM` relevant to this?

Comment: Apologies was meant to say 'stream'

Comment: You should check into whether the BBC actually allow it before you do anything.